# Connet two apps to MariaDB Multi Master database

Tags: mariadb, multi-master-replication

Suppose that we have two application servers(app1 and app2) and also we setup multi master MariaDB clustering with two nodes(node1 and node2) without any HAProxy.Can we connect app1 to node1 and app2 to node2 and also both of app1 and app2 write to node1 and node2?

Does it cause any conflict?

Comment: Maybe my question is more likely the same as this question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124464/what-happens-when-a-mysql-cluster-node-is-disconnected

Comment: Multi-Master?  Or Galera?

Comment: Is really difference between Multi-Master and Galera?As far as i know Galera supports Multi-Master clustering.I mean to use Galera Multi-Master clustering.Maybe i am wrong in using terms!!!

Answer (score 1):

Galera solves most of the problems that occur with Master-Master:

- If one of Master-Master dies, now what?  Galera recovers from any of its 3 nodes failing.
- If you `INSERT` the same `UNIQUE` key value in more than one Master, M-M hangs; Galera complains to the last client to `COMMIT`.
- If a node dies and recovers, the data is automatically repaired.
- You can add a node without manually doing the dump, etc.
- etc.

However, there are a few things that need to be done differently to when using Galera:  [*Tips*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/tips-on-converting-to-galera/)